# python - Sort & Unique vs Set

Tags: python, python-2.7, sorting, set, unique

In python 2.7, in order to retrieve the set of unique strings from a redundant list of strings, what is preferred (~10 million strings of length ~20):

a) sort the list and delete repeating strings

```
sort(l)
unique(l) #some linear time function
```

b) just put them all in a set

```
set(l)
```

Note that I do not care about the order of the strings.

Comment: You can use `timeit` module to be 100% sure but I would be very surprised it a) worked faster than b), since a) requires `O(n + nlogn)` while b) only `O(n)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I made a simple test to check the running time of both solutions. The first test creates a `set` and the second test sorts the list (it doesn't remove duplicates for the sake of simplicity).

As expected creating a set is much faster than sorting, since its complexity is `O(n)` while sorting is `O(nlogn)`.

```
import random
import string
import time


def random_str():
    size = random.randint(10, 20)
    chars = string.ascii_letters + string.digits
    return ''.join(random.choice(chars) for _ in range(size))


l = [random_str() for _ in xrange(1000000)]

t1 = time.clock()
for i in range(10):
    set(l)
t2 = time.clock()
print(round(t2-t1, 3))

t1 = time.clock()
for i in range(10):
    sorted(l)
t2 = time.clock()
print(round(t2-t1, 3))
```

The output I got:

```
2.77
11.83
```

Comment: Using `timeit` is a canonical way to do this kind of measurements, but anyway that's a correct approach. Measure, do not guess.